# Unlist/unnest for a character vector in a dataframe?

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a function or way unlist or unnest a vector within a dataframe using `dplyr`? I have the following example.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(x = 
      c("c(\"Police\", \"Pensions\")",
        "c(\"potato\", \"sweetpotato\")"))
df
# A tibble: 2 x 1
  x                               
  <chr>                           
1 "c(\"Police\", \"Pensions\")"   
2 "c(\"potato\", \"sweetpotato\")"
```

I'd like to get that dataframe column into a format like this.

```
> df
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  x          
  <chr>      
1 Police     
2 Pensions   
3 Potato     
4 Sweetpotato
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is `separate_rows`

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
    separate_rows(x) %>%
    filter(!x %in% c('c', ''))
# A tibble: 4 x 1
#  x          
#  <chr>      
#1 Police     
#2 Pensions   
#3 potato     
#4 sweetpotato
```

NOTE: It would be faster/efficient to separate and `filter`

---

Or another option is to extract the words between th quotes and then `unnest`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(x = str_extract_all(x, '(?<=")[A-Za-z]+')) %>%
   unnest
# A tibble: 4 x 1
#  x          
#  <chr>      
#1 Police     
#2 Pensions   
#3 potato     
#4 sweetpotato
```

#### Benchmarks

On a slightly bigger data,

```
df1 <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), each = 1e5), ]

system.time({
df1 %>% 
    separate_rows(x) %>%
    filter(!x %in% c('c', ''))


})
#. user  system elapsed 
#  0.916   0.033   0.939 


system.time({
df1 %>%
 mutate(x = str_extract_all(x, '(?<=")[A-Za-z]+')) %>%
   unnest

})
#  user  system elapsed 
#  0.763   0.015   0.773 


system.time({

df1 %>% 
  mutate(x = map(x,~eval(parse(text=.)))) %>% 
  unnest

})
#user  system elapsed 
# 15.643   1.813  17.375
```

Comment: I thought `map` was making my solution slow but even `tibble(x=eval(parse(text=string)))` is much slower with `string <- paste0("c(",paste(df1$x,collapse=","),")")` computed separately. It seemed much more economic to me though, I don't get it, maybe the concatenation `c(c(1,2),c(3,4))` to `1:4` is slow.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper. I was also thinking about the single `eval`, but didn't test it.  Good that you tested

Comment: actually I just broke it down and `eval` is fast, `parse` is the slow one.

Answer (score 2):

As you have R code stored in strings I think it's natural to use `eval(parse(text= your_input))`.

Using `unnest` on top of it you get :

```
df %>% 
  mutate(x = map(x,~eval(parse(text=.)))) %>% 
  unnest

# A tibble: 4 x 1
#             x
#         <chr>
# 1      Police
# 2    Pensions
# 3      potato
# 4 sweetpotato
```